# Load local files using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I tried to load some files using `iframe`, but it didn't work.

I want to load a file from: **C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/Courses/c2.pdf** and 
I tried:

`<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/Courses/c2.pdf"></iframe>`

but nothing appears.

How can I load local files using `iframe` or something else?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to serve the framing page from the local folder

Comment: Weirdly enough, I have the same problem, but I used to being able to put my pdf in iframe easily before on chrome. Now it downloads it

Comment: are you using chrome?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably  because of the Same Origin Policy: in this case the iframe is not allowed to load the resource if it is not also served from your localhost. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving html from the server (wamp,xamp) you should put it to local folder relative to the server (localhost/yourfolder/yourfile.pdf). If you're just working with html it should work. I've just tested it and had similar issue on chrome. All of a sudden it started downloading pdf rather then render it. So I had to reinstall browser in order for it to work.